# Как добавить правило для route в образ Wim установочного диска Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, route

Для установленной системы делается так:

```
route -p add 23.218.212.69 MASK 255.255.255.255 0.0.0.0
```

Как это правило добавить по-умолчанию в установщик Windows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создать reg файл

Пример на сайте компании Microsoft: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/141383

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\PersistentRoutes]
"23.218.212.69,255.255.255.255,0.0.0.0,1"=""
```

Comment: еще хороший мануал http://www.pearsonitcertification.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1272743&seqNum=3